# warring flutter : [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated

Tags: flutter

while building apk of my flutter project i get this error :

```
/home/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/move_to_background-1.0.2/android/src/main/java/com/sayegh/move_to_background/MoveToBackgroundPlugin.java:13: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar;
                                              ^
/home/snap/flutter/common/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/move_to_background-1.0.2/android/src/main/java/com/sayegh/move_to_background/MoveToBackgroundPlugin.java:24: warning: [deprecation] Registrar in PluginRegistry has been deprecated
  public static void registerWith(Registrar registrar) {
                                  ^
2 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           49.6s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

idon't khnow if it is related to the plugin move_to_background i use the version   `move_to_background: ^1.0.2` i changed the version but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

So first of all I would recommend using the latest version of the package.

The second point is that you have to sign your app in order to publish it (build in release mode) so Google knows that the app belongs to you.

Check out that tutorial on how to sign your app and publish it to Google Play Store:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g0GNuoCOtaQ

Here are also the official docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Comment: yes i'm using the last version of the plugin but still get the same error

Comment: Ok then try running 'flutter clean' to clean every thing up and if it does not change you cant do anything because the owner has to update his package.

Also it is a warning so your build wont fail but you have to sign your application in order to publish it

Comment: Else your build will fail if you try to build in release mode

Comment: i have the same warning with the plugin move_to_background despite i'm using the last version.